# Adding an OpenId on careers.stackoverflow.com fails with a 404 if the OpenId is assigned to another account

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, openid, merge-accounts

I am trying to change my OpenId from my old email address to a new one. The problem is, I have logged in accidentally with my new account in the past, and so I have an empty account that I don't use, so I cannot change the email address on my current account (account already exists), and when I try to add a new OpenId, I see a "Page not found" error.

How can I remove the empty account and change the OpenId on the current account to use that email address?

Answer (score 1):

**About binding your OpenId to your account**

You can send an email to careers@stackoverflow.com with links to both user accounts which need to be merged

**About the Page not found bug**

After switching accounts (from account 1 to account 2), you were redirected to the user 1 info page, which you couldn't access anymore (since you are now logged-in as user 2): this should now be fixed!

In this case, you will now be redirected to the user info page for the correct account (the one you are logged-in with)

Thank you for the report !